# maximum value of $\int^{\frac{3\pi}{2}}_{-\frac{\pi}{2}}\sin xf(x)dx$ subjected to the condition$|f(x)|\leq 5$

Tags: calculus

maximum value of $\displaystyle \int^{\frac{3\pi}{2}}_{-\frac{\pi}{2}}\sin xf(x)dx$ subjected to the condition$|f(x)|\leq 5$

could some help me with this, thanks

Comment: no parcy Taxel i could,t  i did,t understand how can i start it

Comment: Let it be clear: condition $|f(x)| \leq 5$ must hold for **all** $x \in [-\pi/2,3\pi/2]$ for any function $f$ ? No hypothesis on $f$, continuous, etc... ?

Comment: @JeanMarie: If $f(x)$ were required to be continuous, you wouldn't have a maximum value for the integral (you can take closer and closer approximations to $5sgn(\sin(x))$ ).

Comment: Yes, you are right, according to the way the question is formulated, we are looking for a maximum and not a supremum ("sup"). Nevertheless, it would have been fine if the OP had answered my question about supplementary conditions on $f$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $|f(x)|\le 5$ for all $x\in \left[-\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{3\pi}{2}\right]$, we have $\sin(x) f(x)\le|\sin(x) f(x)|\le 5|\sin(x)|$ for all $x\in\left[-\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{3\pi}{2}\right]$.

We thus have $$\int_{-\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\frac{3\pi}{2}}\sin(x)f(x)\mathrm{dx}\le\int_{-\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\frac{3\pi}{2}}5|\sin(x)|\mathrm{dx}$$

But we have $$\int_{-\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\frac{3\pi}{2}}5|\sin(x)|\mathrm{dx}=20$$

Hence $$\int_{-\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\frac{3\pi}{2}}\sin(x)f(x)\mathrm{dx}\le 20$$

Thus the upper bound for the maximum value of $\displaystyle\int_{-\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\frac{3\pi}{2}}\sin(x)f(x)\mathrm{dx}$ is $20$.

If we let $f(x):=-5$ for $x\in\left[-\frac{\pi}{2},0\right]\cap\left[\pi,\frac{3\pi}{2}\right]$ and $f(x):=5$ for $x\in (0,\pi)$, then one has $\displaystyle\int_{-\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\frac{3\pi}{2}}\sin(x)f(x)\mathrm{dx}=20$. Since this is the same as the upper bound for maximum value, the maximum value of $\displaystyle\int_{-\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\frac{3\pi}{2}}\sin(x)f(x)\mathrm{dx}$ is $20$.

Answer (score 3):

Hint: Argue that
$$f(x)=5\cdot sgn(\sin(x))$$
gives you the maximum, where sgn is the sign-function

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

$\displaystyle \int^{\frac{3\pi}{2}}_{-\frac{\pi}{2}}\sin xf(x)dx\leq \int^{\frac{3\pi}{2}}_{-\frac{\pi}{2}}|\sin xf(x)|dx\leq 5\int^{\frac{3\pi}{2}}_{-\frac{\pi}{2}}|\sin x|dx$

Comment: This only gives an upper bound for the maximum, not the maximum.

Comment: @Clayton What Takahiro Waki has written should be considered as **complementary** to the hint of DURGESH TIWARI. With these two hints, the OP has the answer...

Comment: @JeanMarie: Durgesh Tiwari ..is.. the OP.